# C# Outlook 2007 Addin + Embedded Assemblies

Tags: c#, assemblies, embedded-resource, outlook-addin, assemblyresolve

I'm creating an Outlook Addin and want to see if I can embed the dependent DLLs using             `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve`, but I have no idea where to add this so that it will actually get called/fired :(

Which method should the event handler be subscribed within so that I can load the assemblies?

Help!